# Intellitest command line invocation

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, pex, intellitest

For my academic research i am trying to invoke intellitest from command line. I was using this with Pex older version through (pexwizard and pex commands) and this was generating an html report. I am now using vs 2015 and trying to do something similar but cannot find a way. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36885783/visual-studio-intellitest-execution-through-command-line

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your feedback. IntelliTest does not support a command line yet. Please do indicate your interest by voting here: http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/8623015-enable-intellitest-to-run-in-the-build-pipeline