# Visual studio Intellitest execution through command line

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, intellitest

I have vs2015 enterprise edition.I would like to run the IntelliTest through command and generate reports. Is there any way I can invoke this through command line.

Answer (score 0):

IntelliTest does not support a command line yet. We are tracking that as a feature request here: http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/8623015-enable-intellitest-to-run-in-the-build-pipeline. Please consider voting.

Comment: Thanks for the update. When we can expect this feature?

Comment: I cannot commit on a date by when this feature can be expected. We are watching the uservoice feature request carefully, however.
What kind of reports do you want to generate? Since IntelliTest generates traditional unit tests, you may want to consider any existing reporting mechanisms.

Comment: Thanks for your time. Using pex 2010 power tools I am able to generate the data driven test results using command line by passing Test.dll as parameter. Pex.exe is automatically instrumenting my Test.dll and generating reports in a html format. I looking for a similar functionality in IntelliTest.

Comment: Please see my comment in the Q&A section of that power tools page. "Smart Unit Tests" as it was briefly called before we named it IntelliTest is the supported version - therefore kindly consider switching to using IntelliTest.